# Create the name of nest hash map dynamically in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic, hashmap

**Issue:**

New to Java, trying to populate the name of nested HashMap dynamically, how should I modify line 10

- So that the result would align with below, in order to perform actions on the nested HashMap;
- Or maybe the name does not matter?

**Expected Results:**

```
Node(A, tempA)
Node(B, tempB)
...
Node(Z, tempZ)
```

**Code:**

```
Note that there are blocks of code excluded in the middle, so to focus on the approach for the question above.

1  private Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> nodes = new HashMap<>();
2 
3  String [] letters = new String[26];
4      for (int i = 0; i <26; i++){
5          char temp = (char) (65 + i);
6          letters[i] = String.valueOf(temp);
7      }
8
9  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
10    HashMap<String, Integer> tempA = new HashMap<>();
11    nodes.put(letters[i], tempA);
12 }
```

Comment: Why does the name matter?

Comment: What is the purpose?.  But in any event, just create the maps in your first loop.  No Array of letters is needed.

Comment: Not sure I have an answer, but I can tell you that when you have a `Map<Something,Map<>>` you probably should have some intermediate class handling the logic. Not 100% of the time, but like 98% of the time.